# How do I make an extension that automatically enables flash on a site?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Here's some examples:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gamepoint-flash-enabler/hondlccdejidmimngjiikdpfojbkamlf

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/habboon-automatic-flash-a/akcafbaobcipanhmmfmkpneejopclhfg

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cprewritten-flash-enabler/dkgjegocmcicmloagcapoglndjkhpdmm

I want to make one of these extensions but for my website, I'm assuming it's not as simple as just copying and pasting the code and changing the url to my site, so I would really really appreciate any support I could have.

Comment: It is just as simple as that, most probably. Anyway, you need to try it, then post a question on StackOverflow with details and [MCVE](/help/mcve) on what works and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!
If you go to:
`C:\Users\<your computer username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`
You can find the extensions you have installed on Chrome.

I used the two examples and downloaded them; then looked at the files within that extension to understand the code on how they work and how they are made.